# cakephp upgrade shell debug kit error

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I' m trying to use cakephp upgrade shell to migrate my project to cakephp 1.3 -> 2.0.1  but when i run the script, it; s returning the following error:

```
Error: Plugin DebugKit could not be found.
#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/youppie/lib/Cake/Core/App.php(328): CakePlugin::path('DebugKit')
#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/youppie/lib/Cake/Console/Command/UpgradeShell.php(223): App::pluginPath('DebugKit')
#2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/youppie/lib/Cake/Console/Command/UpgradeShell.php(91): UpgradeShell->helpers()
#3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/youppie/lib/Cake/Console/Shell.php(372): UpgradeShell->all()
#4 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/youppie/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(177): Shell->runCommand('all', Array)
#5 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/youppie/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(69): ShellDispatcher->dispatch()
#6 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/youppie/app/Console/cake.php(41): ShellDispatcher::run(Array)
#7 {main}
```

I' m running `./Console/cake upgrade upgrade all --dry-run` inside app directory

Anyone knows what i'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, move your plugins folder out of the app, so it is not affected during the upgrade. You could also leave the folder there, but just move the contents of it out of the scene.

Also remember that in 2.0, plugins need to be loaded manually. In your bootstrap file add CakePlugin::loadAll() or just CakePlugin::load('MyPlugin')